# Getting recently added object. Django

Tags: django

How to get only recently added `Order`?

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUSS = (
        (u'E', u'Expected'),
        (u'S', u'Sent'),
        (u'F', u'Finished'),
        )

    who = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Owner')
    products = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    send = models.ForeignKey(Send)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, choices=STATUSS, default='O')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *recently* you mean the most recent order regarding the date it was added then you can use:

```
Order.objects.order_by('-date')[0]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why do you say that? This queryset will give him the most recent order.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate answer to a pretty vague question.

Comment: I need just recently added single object

Comment: I try: Order.objects.filter(who=k).order_by('date')[0].update(send=send_option) but does not work. Thanks

Comment: You cannot use `update` directly because `Order.objects.filter(who=k).order_by('date')[0]` returns a single object not a queryset.Use instead `x=Order.objects.filter(who=k).order_by('date')[0]` and then `x.send=send_option` and then `x.save()`.

Comment: most recently means a larger date, thus you need to order by `-date`

Comment: Thank you thinkonom. Now I have: Cannot assign "1": "Order.send" must be a "Send" instance. - Perhaps because this is ForeignKey.

Comment: Yes. You probably have to do something like: `k=Send.objects.get(...=send_option)` and then `x.send=k`

Answer (score 3):

I prefer auto-increment `pk`, then

```
Order.objects.latest('pk')
```

It's simpler, indexed and is ready as long as the default surrogate primary key is used.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of "recently" is "the last added", you can use `latest()`

```
Order.objects.latest('date')
```

or just

```
Order.objects.latest()
```

if you have

```
class Meta:
    get_latest_by = 'date'
```

in your model. This is from the django docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest

If you want more than one of the most recent, say everything from the last 5 days:

```
import datetime
Order.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=5))
```

or if you want the last 10 records regardless of how recent, then:

```
Order.objects.order_by('-date')[10]
```